# Blank payload when sending POST via Micropython

Tags: python, json, micropython

I want to call POST from micropython to Django webserver.
The POST payload shows up as empty when called from the micropython code.
When the same code is ran with C-Python, it does show up with the filled payload.

Here is the micropython code -

```
import urequests as requests

url = "http://192.168.0.33:8000/species/"

payload={'name': 'test12',
'classification': 'sheep12',
'language': 'sheep_lang12'}
files=[

]
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print('success')
print(response.text)
```

The output of response.txt is -
*{'name':'',classification:'',language:''}*

I also tried using an alternative of the payload to use JSON. Here is the JSON payload attempt

```
import urequests as requests
import ujson as json

url = "http://192.168.0.33:8000/species/"

payload={'name': 'test12',
'classification': 'sheep12',
'language': 'sheep_lang12'}
files=[

]
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print('success')
print(response.text)
```

What did I miss here ?